# Is it OK to use '\ ' after initials in BibTeX files?

Tags: bibtex

We share a large BibTeX files at work and I have noticed that there are many entries with `\`  after initials, for ex. `author = {D.P.\ Bertsekas}` or `author = {D.\ P.\ Bertsekas}`.
Is there any benefit to this? (I think I understand the reason: to avoid large space after the full stop - but I would expect BibTeX to be smart enough to avoid it anyway?)

And, more importantly, can it cause problems?

And what about `author = {Bertsekas, D.\ P.\ }`? This is what actually made me aware of the issue, because JabRef has since v. 5.0 started stripping trailing spaces, so it re-saves it as `author = {Bertsekas, D.\ P.\}` .. and that *is* a problem...
(A side question: should it be considered a bug in JabRef, if it breaks a working file, albeit one with strange syntax?)

Comment: Instead of wondering whether to input the author's initials as `D.P.\ Bertsekas`, `D.\ P.\ Bertsekas`, or (much better!) as `D. P. Bertsekas`, I would go the opposite route, i.e., I'd provide the author's *full* given names, viz., as either `Dimitri Panteli Bertsekas` or `Dimitri P. Bertsekas`. That way, you can let the bibliography style be fully in charge of whether to show full or abbreviated given names and, if it's the latter, *how* the abbreviated given names should be displayed.

Comment: To answer your side question: If JabRef changes field data in a way that breaks files that worked fine earlier, then I would definitely report it to the developers. Even if they decide that the use case is too outlandish, but then it is still documented. (In this case I'm pretty sure that `author = {Bertsekas, D.\ P.\ },` and `author = {Bertsekas, D.\ P.\}` are about equally bad, though.)

Comment: @Mico I personally also prefer to use full names and leave the abbreviations on BibTeX styles, but this question is about a file shared by many with different preferences (and going back many years). So, I do not want to change others' entries unless they are wrong.

Comment: Yes, LaTeX is smart enough to recognise `D. P. Bertsekas` as initials and not use a large space (anywhere in the document). It also doesn't use large spaces in the bibliography at all unless specifically told to do so (with `\newblock`).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**tl;dr** I would *not* use `\`  after given name initials.

---

### `\`  suppresses desirable automatically inserted ties (`~`)

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author  = {A. Alpha},
  title   = {Title A},
  year    = {2010},
}
@book{b,
  author  = {B.\ Beta},
  title   = {Title B},
  year    = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `.bbl` file contains

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{a}
A.~Alpha.
\newblock {\em Title A}.
\newblock 2010.

\bibitem{b}
B.\ Beta.
\newblock {\em Title B}.
\newblock 2020.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Which means that BibTeX automatically inserts a `~` if you input the name as `A. Alpha`, but not if you input it as `B.\ Beta`.

Since `~` avoids a line break after the initial, I'd argue that the form with `~` is more desirable here. In this case the `\`  is therefore detrimental.

---

### `.\`  does generally not behave different than `.`  in bibliographies

The situation is prima facie different in

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author  = {Anne A. Alpha},
  title   = {Title A},
  year    = {2010},
}
@book{b,
  author  = {Berta B.\ Beta},
  title   = {Title B},
  year    = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

where we get

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{a}
Anne~A. Alpha.
\newblock {\em Title A}.
\newblock 2010.

\bibitem{b}
Berta~B.\ Beta.
\newblock {\em Title B}.
\newblock 2020.

\end{thebibliography}
```

This time `Anne~A. Alpha` has a normal space, but `Berta~B.\ Beta` a control space.

In all standard bibliography setups that I know of, there is no practical difference between the two though, since the bibliography is set with `` \sfcode`\.\@m `` or `\frenchspacing`, which means that spaces after `.`s are not enlarged (as usually the case with `\nonfrenchspacing`).

What's more `A. Alpha` and `A.\ Alpha` already behave the same in a 'normal' document context (thanks to [Especially Lime](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/119585/especially-lime) for pointing that out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551139/is-it-ok-to-use-after-initials-in-bibtex-files/551144#comment1392138_551139)). Since uppercase letters have a different space factor than lowercase letters, a space following a period after an uppercase letter will result in a normal space.

Of course it would theoretically be possible to change the standard behaviour such that `.\`  and `.`  behave differently, but it is reasonable not to expect this to be the case.

---

### `\` may end up in the `.bbl` output turning characters into macros

There can be more problems if `\`  comes at the end of a field/name part and the space is discarded

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author  = {Bertsekas, D.\ P.\ },
  title   = {Title A},
  year    = {2010},
}
@book{b,
  author  = {Bertsekas, D.\ P.\},
  title   = {Title B},
  year    = {2015},
}
@book{c,
  author  = {D.\ P.\ Bertsekas},
  title   = {Title C},
  year    = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b,c}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{a}
D.\~P.\ Bertsekas.
\newblock {\em Title A}.
\newblock 2010.

\bibitem{b}
D.\~P.\ Bertsekas.
\newblock {\em Title B}.
\newblock 2015.

\bibitem{c}
D.\~P.\ Bertsekas.
\newblock {\em Title C}.
\newblock 2020.

\end{thebibliography}
```

which comes out as

[image: D.P(with tilde).]

The problem here is not the removal of the trailing space at the end (I'd have to check this, but I'm pretty sure BibTeX automatically discards leading and trailing space). The problem is that BibTeX inserts `~` between the name parts, which gets combined with `\` to `\~`, so puts a tilde over the next character.

Because BibTeX is not LaTeX it is not a `.bib`-syntax error to say

```
author = {Name\},
```

but then BibTeX will assume the name is `Name\`. If the name is then printed in the `.bbl` file the `\` may end up next to another character that then gets turned into a macro.

---

### The documentation only mentions `D. E. Knuth`

The version with `\`  is definitely not encouraged or even mentioned in any of the official BibTeX documentation that I know of. `btxdoc` only has

```
author = {D. E. Knuth},
```

So I would argue this is the intended input for initials.

The `\`  is generally more likely to have negative side effects and only has no benefits in standard setups. I would avoid it.

Just to recap

- BibTeX can already automatically insert unbreakable space instead of a normal space in some places. In particular `D. P. Bertsekas` will become `D.~P.~Bertsekas` with most styles. `~` is probably preferred over   or `\`   here.
- `.\`  and `.`   will generally behave the same in the bibliography (and for the name use case even anywhere)
- BibTeX may strip spaces in some contexts, which may cause `\`  to become only a backslash `\`, which may in unfortunate circumstances end up in places where it turns things into macros that were not intended to be macros.

---

Note that `D.P. Bertsekas` should ideally be `D. P. Bertsekas`, since `abbrv` abbreviates `D.P. Bertsekas` to "D. Bertsekas" because it can't tell that "D.P." are two initials and not one first name.

Comment: This is a comment from barbara beeton (who's having posting problems at the moment): Regarding the handling of author names by BibTeX, at least some document classes process bibliographic material using `\frenchspacing` so it's not necessary to do anything special to avoid the wider spaces. There's a more insidious problem associated with persons having "prefixed" names that shouldn't be reduced to single initials. Two such individuals are `Nicholas {DeB}. Katzenbach` and `Neil {DeG}rasse Tyson`.

Answer (score 0):

As seen, there are variable answers to this, but it sounds as if the main problem here is consensus in your user base. I should get them together to achieve that consensus before any further moves. `\`  is employed to enforce spacing; the same is employed after `\rq` to do so, unless there's a comma or full-stop in place, but it's not the code format which needs to be clarified here before a format is determined.

Comment: I tried to fix the code highlighting. Please roll back the edit if I changed the intended meaning of what you wrote (I changed `\'` to `\ `, which I *think* is what you want in this context).